# igualar vetores usando variaveis

Tags: python

Pessoal comecei agora no python, gostaria de saber o que esta errado nesse codigo. Eu queria passar os numeros de `valores` para `valoresI` pulando sempre uma posição, por isso o `x += 2`. Mas ele fica dando erro.
Se eu colocar `valoresI[4] = valores[4]` ele até vai, mas eu precisava usar uma variavel que mudasse esse valor de 2 em 2

```py
while x <= 10:

    valoresI[x] = valores[x]
    x += 2
```

Comment: Qual error? Pelo que vejo pode ser esse "x" aí, nessa caso o resultado da tua lista valoresl vai ser metade da lista valores correto? Então voce pode fazer x = 0, e então rodar um laço while que vai iterar sua lista/2 e cada iteração o x será icrementado por 2

Comment: como você inicializou `x`, `valoresI` e `valores`?

Comment: valores = [] 
valoresI = [] 
x = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque você precisa inicializar a variável. Você está tentando adicionar 2 à ela, mas ela não existe ainda, então não tem valor.

Lembre que uma variável `nula` não é o mesmo que ela ser igual a `0`.

Se os seus vetores estão ok, então simplesmente inicializar a variável deve resolver seu problema:

```
x = 0;
while x <= 10:
    valoresI[x] = valores[x]
    x += 2
```

Note que um for cairia bem nessa situação

```
for x in range(0, 10, 2):
    valoresI[x] = valores[x]
```

Comment: muito obrigado, resolveu meu probelma